# com_messages like component

Tags: joomla2.5

I want to develop a custom component that have tabs like com_messages built in component to joomla 2.5. Any one can guide me?

I look into it but not getting it
http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_categories

Comment: you mean tabs `New Private Message` & `Messages` ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can easily create your own compoenent by using the following website..

```
http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/
```

Just create an account and create your own component... All the best..

Comment: wt if i want to do it customly not with any softweare? iwant to add tabs to my component but ir wont allow my to add any thing like this wt could i possibly do?

Comment: i want to show data of two tables in separate panels at backend of joomla 2.5